# SQL PDO Query() method

Tags: php, pdo

Ok I have an issue. I am trying to verify the legitimacy of a user by checking their inputted email address (user name) and password. The users table has the following columns:

```
#   Name               Type          Collation      
     1  User_ID     int(10)UNSIGNED 
     3  Phone       bigint(10)              
     4  Street_Address  varchar(30)     latin1_swedish_ci       
     5  Apartment   int(5)              
     6  City        varchar(35)     latin1_swedish_ci            
     7  State       varchar(35)     latin1_swedish_ci           
     8  Zip_Code    int(5)              
     10 Login_Password  char(32)        latin1_swedish_ci               
     11 UserType    varchar(5)      latin1_swedish_ci
```

After I validate the input for email and password and they satisfy their constraints. I set a Boolean variable "$insert" to true. Next I have the following PHP code:

```
$check= "SELECT Name FROM users WHERE Email='$emailLogin' AND Login_Password='$passwordLogin'";

if(($result= ($db->query($check))) != false) // <--- PROBLEM HERE
     {
             $resultArray = $result->fetch();
             $name= $resultArray['Name'];

             $checkID= "SELECT User_ID FROM users WHERE Name= '$name'";
             $idResult= $db->query($checkID);

             if(count($idResult) >0)
             {
                $idArray= $idResult->fetch();
                $id= $idArray['User_ID'];
                    echo "userID is = ". $id;
                $_SESSION['user']= $name;
                $_SESSION['login']= true;
                $_SESSION['userID']= $id;
                //header('location:../view/userHome.php');
             }
             else
             {
                 include("../view/error.php?message=19");
                 exit();
             }
     }
     else
     {

         header("location: ../controller/login.php");
     }
}//end function
```

Long story short "if($result= ($db->query($check))) != false " which I have in the code above if causing me problems. I should never enter the if clause if no matching email address and password is found, but it is. 
Can someone help me either point out the FLAW in my code or give me a better way to check.

just in case you need the "database.php" file here it is:

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store';
    $username = 'alex';
    $password = 'asdf1234';

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        include('database_error.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

database.php

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store';
$username = 'alex';
$password = 'asdf1234';
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
);
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
```

note that there shouldn't be no dedicated `database_error.php` file but rather generalized error page shown by error handler.

note the ERRMODE thing which is most essential for your problem. It will tell you what is actually wrong with your query.

and here goes the proper code for password check, with all the tons of useless code taken away.

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, User_ID FROM users WHERE Email= ? AND Login_Password=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([$emailLogin, $passwordLogin]);
if($row = $stm->fetch())
{
    $_SESSION['user']   = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['id'];
    header('location:../view/userHome.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
    header("location: ../controller/login.php");
    exit();
}
```

long story short: query() result will be false only in case of **query error.** So, you cannot use it to check the password wither way. You have to check fetched value instead. Yet it cleraly says that there is an error with your query which you have to fix first.

Running 2 queries against the same table to get two different values from the same row makes very little sense. As well as numerous variable assignments.

and oh, yes. NEVER use `query()` with dynamically built queries. You are ought to use prepare/execute with placeholders instead.

Comment: Your Common Sense, I really appreciate all of your help. Thanks for the detailed and well explained answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following

database.php

`$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store", 'alex', 'asdf1234');`

login page

`$_query = "SELECT Name, User_ID FROM users WHERE Email= :email AND Login_Password=:password";`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($_query); 
$stmt->bindparam(":email",$_POST['email']); 
$stmt->bindparam(":password",$_POST['password']);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
if($total > 0)
{
    //code here that you want   
}
```